# AWK command to change epoch time to date and list epoch on same line

Tags: time, awk, line, epoch

So right now I have:

```
echo -n "Enter Path (or File if in directory) to Convert: " ; read FILE ; cat $FILE | awk '{print strftime("%c",$1)} {print}'
```

This prints the following, when a file or path is entered to be converted:

```
Tue 04 Dec 2012 09:48:43 PM PST
1354686523
Wed 05 Dec 2012 09:47:38 PM PST
1354772858
Thu 06 Dec 2012 09:47:39 PM PST
1354859259
Fri 07 Dec 2012 09:46:08 PM PST
1354945568
```

The above is just an example date.  This is perfect, but how do I get this to be on the same line?  So it shows each date in the file like this:

```
Tue 04 Dec 2012 09:48:43 PM PST  --  1354686523
Wed 05 Dec 2012 09:47:38 PM PST  --  1354772858
Thu 06 Dec 2012 09:47:39 PM PST  --  1354859259
Fri 07 Dec 2012 09:46:08 PM PST  --  1354945568
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try:

```
awk '{ printf "%s -- %s\n", strftime("%c",$1), $0 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR%2==0 {printf(" -- %s\n", $0) }
     NR%2==1 {printf("%s ", $0)} ' inputfile > outputfile
```

Try that.  Fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax error.. if it helps im on XShell (linux terminal)